# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'some_module'

Tags: python, module, package

Could anyone please point me where I am going wrong ??? I tried all options , I don't want to go with adding sys.path option..

Below is my project structure, I am trying to import module

```
  from pipeline_modules.pdf2docx_convertor import * 

  Getting error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipeline_modules'
```

I printed sys.path values

```
   ['c:\\microservice\\pdf_processing_pipepline\\pipeline', 'C:\\microservice_env\\python39.zip', 'C:\\microservice_env\\DLLs', 'C:\\microservice_env\\lib', 'C:\\microservice_env', 'C:\\microservice_env\\lib\\site-packages']
```

[image]

Comment: What module are you running to get this error?

Comment: I am directly running the file orchestrator.py from vscode run option

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `pipeline_modules` is in the parent directory of `orchestrator.py` Python is unable to import packages in a parent directory. Here are some things you can do:

- Move `pipeline_modules` to the same directory as orchestrator
- Add `pipeline_modules` to `sys.path`
- If you are on Linux, make a symlink with `ln -sv ../pipeline_modules ./pipeline_modules`

Also try running with `python3 orchestrator.py` instead of the vs code run option.

Comment: not working..I cannot move the directory, also tried running with python3 getting same erorr

Comment: If you are on Linux, try making a symlink